# magento with wordpress in subdirectory htaccess issue

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, magento

I've been given the dubious honour of taking over a customers magento sites and moving them to a new server.

The sites has wordpress installed in a sub directory of of magento (magento is in / and wordpress in /blog/wordpress)

The problem is the default magento htaccess catches the wordpress URL's because it's designed to catch anything that isn't a file..

Is there a way to bypass this action in magento's htaccess, so that the wordpress htaccess can go its thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(blog|wordpress)($|/) - [L]
```

The above htaccess rule applied before any of the other rules seems to work!